# Is there a way to pass a query parameter to a google calendar link that will pop up the working locations selector?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I would like to be able to share a link that will show the working location "pop up" in google calendar.

I have looked in to the regular create event's view  "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit", but I can't find anything simliar for the "working locations event".

[image]